# How to add ahref to li without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

My Javascript code looks like this :

```
function to_ul(branches) {
var ul = document.createElement("ul");


for (var i=0, n=branches.length; i<n; i++) {
  var branch = branches[i];
  var li = document.createElement("li");


    var text = document.createTextNode(branch.name);
    li.appendChild(text);

    if (branch.branches) {
         li.appendChild(to_ul(branch.branches));
         li.className="parent";
    }

    ul.appendChild(li);        
}
return ul;
}
```

It's working fine (text branches are in a JSON) but how can I add a a `href` linking to `#` to the text in my list items without jQuery ?

Comment: maybe your question is not clear. Can you post the expected html result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the

```
var text = document.createTextNode(branch.name);
```

line with:

```
var text = document.createElement('a');
text.setAttribute('href', '#');
text.innerHTML = branch.name;
```

Edit: Instead of `innerHTML`, you can also use

```
text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(branch.name));
```

Comment: Why are you using `innerHTML` instead of `createTextNode`?

Comment: @PeeHaa No particular reason, I thought it would work just as well(it will be slightly slower, google tells me). I've edited my answer to include the `createTextNode` code as well.

Answer (score -1):

In your loop, just create an other element, `<a>` after your `<li>` :

```
var li = document.createElement("li"); // your code
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "http://whatever"; // or a.href = "#"+branch.name
a.innerHTML = "link name";
li.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Your solution works but all the links turn to : "link name".

a.innerHTML = branch.name; does the trick. Thanks for your input.

Comment: well of course you have to adapt it to what you really want. You would probably want to also add `a.title = "link name, or longer desc"` (not this exact string but whatever you want)